# jquery click if else statement not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, onclick

im trying to input a text and then place that text to a specific div box by clicking one of the box options

html code:

```
<input class="textField" type="text">

  <div class="sendToBox1">send to box 1</div>
  <div class="sendToBox2">send to box 2</div>
  
  <div class="box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">box 2</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input1 = $('.textField');
  
  var $sendToBox;
  var $selectedBox;
  
  if($(".sendToBox1").on("click")) {
     $sendToBox = $(".sendToBox1");
     $selectedBox = $(".box1");
  } else if($(".sendToBox2").on("click")) {
     $sendToBox = $(".sendToBox2");
     $selectedBox = $(".box2");
  }

  $($sendToBox).click(function() {
    $($selectedBox).append($input1.val());
    $input1.val('');
  });
  
});
```

what i want the if else statement to do is store the class name .sendToBox1 or .sendToBox2 as a value to $sendToBox, depending on which box option is clicked and the same goes to .box1 or .box2 being stored as a value to variable $selectedBox. upon clicking one of the box options, class names should be stored inside the 2 variables, at the same time places the text to the chosen div box. the problem is that the else if statement does not seem to work.

what happens is after typing a text, i click send to box 1, it stored the class names .sendToBox1 and .box1 to variables $sendToBox and $selectedBox which then also successfully places the text to box 1 but after typing another text and trying to place the text inside the second box by clicking the 2nd box option, it doesn't work. it might help to run it on your own device to see the problem a lot better. i hope my explanation was understandable and that someone can help fix the code. thanks.

Comment: Why are you placing an event handler in an `if`?

Comment: was that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery methods chain - so $(".sendToBox1").on("click") == $(".sendToBox1") (sort of, not exactly) so your if statement is if (jquery_is_an_object) which it always is.

Rather than think *"if box1 is clicked"*, think of it as "*when box1 is clicked*", which is just another event handler.

Without changing the concept of your code too much, this looks like what you intended:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input1 = $('.textField');

  var $sendToBox;
  var $selectedBox;

  $(".sendToBox1").on("click", function() {
    $selectedBox = $(".box1");
  });
  $(".sendToBox2").on("click", function() {
    $selectedBox = $(".box2");
  });

  $(".sendToBox1,.sendToBox2").click(function() {
    $($selectedBox).append($input1.val());
    $input1.val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="textField" type="text">

  <div class="sendToBox1">send to box 1</div>
  <div class="sendToBox2">send to box 2</div>
  
  <div class="box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">box 2</div>
```

However, this doesn't "feel" right as there are multiple click handlers for the same events.  Instead, move the "send to" part to its own function and call from the event handlers:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input1 = $('.textField');

  var $sendToBox;
  var $selectedBox;

  $(".sendToBox1").on("click", function() {
    sendTo($input1, $(".box1"));
  });
  $(".sendToBox2").on("click", function() {
    sendTo($input1, $(".box2"));
  });
  
  function sendTo(from, to) {
     to.append(from.val());
     from.val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="textField" type="text">

  <div class="sendToBox1">send to box 1</div>
  <div class="sendToBox2">send to box 2</div>
  
  <div class="box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">box 2</div>
```

Which leads to the next step: what if you want to add send to / box 3?   Repeat the same code?   Instead, write your code so that it's data-driven:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input1 = $('.textField');

  $(".sendTo").on("click", function() {
    var box = $(this).data("sendto");
    $(`[data-box='${box}']`).append($input1.val())
    $input1.val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="textField" type="text">

  <div class="sendTo" data-sendto='box1'>send to box 1</div>
  <div class="sendTo" data-sendto='box2'>send to box 2</div>
  
  <div data-box="box1">box 1</div>
  <div data-box="box2">box 2</div>
```

Now, when it comes to add another box, you can just add:

```
<div class="sendTo" data-sendto='box3'>send to box 3</div>
<div data-box="box3">box 3</div>
```

and not make any code changes.

In this case, even if you never add that 3rd box, the code is still more succint.

Comment: im sorry to ask this but what if you want to include a localstorage on the third step

Comment: Not clear what you mean "include localstorage" - but assuming your localstorage is key-based, then data-driven code would indicate that that key would be stored in data- attributes on the HTML.  (data-driven doesn't mean data- attributes, that's just how the data is stored/passed to the js, it could be eg json)

Comment: yes the key-based one. im having trouble where to place the getItem and setItem. if it can't be applied to the third one, the second one's good.

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer if it helped you answer the question that you asked, then ask a new question regarding localstage, including your code (eg with it working for option 2) and asking how to implement it for option 3.  If you add a link here, I'll likely pick it up and have a look, but otherwise someone else will also likely provide an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771254/problem-with-local-storage-getitem-and-setitem. i asked how to implement it on the third option. you won't see any code changes. i barely had any idea how to use it on the second option. btw your answer did help the question i asked before