# problem with local storage getItem and setItem

Tags: jquery, local-storage

is there a way to use localstorage on the code below? just to make sure that the text you typed remains on the box you sent it to even after refreshing.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $input1 = $('.textField');
   
   $(".sendTo").on("click", function() {
      var box = $(this).data("sendto");
      $(`[data-box='${box}']`).append($input1.val());
      $input1.val("");
   });
});
```

html:

```
<input class="textField" type="text">
  <div class="sendTo" data-sendto='box1'>send to box 1</div>   
  <div class="sendTo" data-sendto='box2'>send to box 2</div> 
  <div data-box="box1">box 1</div>
  <div data-box="box2">box 2</div>
```

im having trouble where to place the `localStorage.setItem` and`localStorage.getItem`

Comment: where are you setting and getting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this code with localstorage.setItem / getItem you just need to know the key to read.  That's already passed in the box variable:

```
var box = $(this).data("sendto");
```

so you can use it as:

```
localStorage.setItem(box, output.text())
```

To retrieve with `getItem` you can loop each output that has attribute `[data-box]`, get the `.data("box")` and use that as the key:

```
   $("[data-box]").each(function() { 
      var box = $(this).data("box");
      var val = localStorage.getItem(box);
      $(this).text(val);
   });
```

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $input1 = $('.textField');
   
   $("[data-box]").each(function() { 
      var box = $(this).data("box");
      var val = localStorage.getItem(box);
      $(this).text(val);
   });
   
   $(".sendTo").on("click", function() {
      var box = $(this).data("sendto");
      var output = $(`[data-box='${box}']`);
      output.append($input1.val());
      $input1.val("");
      localStorage.setItem(box, output.text());
   });
});
```

Note: stackoverflow snippets don't allow localstorage, so you can use this fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/35ugqf6j/

Note: this clears the default "box 1" text in the outputs - you can check for `null` if you don't want that on the first run.

Note: you'll need a method to clear the output/localstorage otherwise it just gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: may i know which part of the code i should check for null

Comment: `var val = localStorage.getItem(box); if (val != null) $(this).text(val)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this (see comments for more explanation):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        var $input1 = $('.textField'); 

        // when page is loaded then get possible value from storage
        var val = localStorage.getItem('savedtext');

        // if there is something stored, write it into the inputfield
        if (val != undefined && val != '') {
            $input1.val(val);
        }

        $(".sendTo").on("click", function () {

            // on click save the value of the inputfield to localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('savedtext', $input1.val());

            var box = $(this).data("sendto");
            $(`[data-box='${box}']`).append($input1.val());
            $input1.val("");
        });
    });
```

You can also save the data on every keypress if you add this event registration on the input-field:

```
$input1.on("keyup", function () {

    // if you want to save it not only on click
    // but all the time
    localStorage.setItem('savedtext', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: OP's question is a follow-on question from [this original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75760018/2181514) (which wasn't about localstorage).   They are trying to use data-driven code - ie changes to the HTML still work without needing to add new ".box3".click code etc.   They have 1 input which can be sent to either box1 or box2 and want to save box1/box - the outputs, not the input, which gets cleared.